# How to download file in ASCII mode using python ftp connection

Tags: python, file, ftp, download, connection

Can we download file in ASCII mode using python ftp connection ?

I have only below binary mode method,
ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)

I want to know how I can download ASCII mode.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can download files by

> ftp.retlines

I recommend you to refer to a following official document.
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.retrlines

You can find a lot of samples!
http://nullege.com/codes/search/ftplib.FTP.retrlines

Answer (score 0):

Use retrlines instead of retrbinary:

```
local_file = open(filename, 'w')
ftp.retrlines('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.append)
local_file.close()
```

Comment: For some reason this is not creating new lines when downloading source from fixed block file with logical record length.  Just one long record. More research required.